# How to find a total of row values in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the total of rows that have a column value of 3 or 4. That being said, the first row has only one value of 3 so if I create a new column

```
currentdx_count1$TotalDiagnoses
```

That new column called TotalDiagnoses should only have a value of 1 under it for the first row. I have tried

```
currentdx_count1$TotalDiagnoses <- rowSums(currentdx_count1[2:32])
```

This doesn't give me what I need as expected because it literally sums up the whole row. That being said, is there an existing function that does what I want to do or will I have to make one? Could I specify more in rowSums for it to work as I need it to?

Thanks for any and all help.

Edit: I'm trying to adapt a method I use earlier in my script that works for a similar purpose

```
findtotal <- endsWith(names(currentdx_count1), 'Current')
findtotal <- lapply(findtotal, `>`, 2)
findtotal <- unlist(findtotal)
currentdx_count1$TotalDiagnoses <- currentdx_count1[c(findtotal)]
```

I get an error which I have never seen before (an error in view?!)
So I tried just this

```
findtotal <- endsWith(names(currentdx_count1), 'Current')
currentdx_count1$TotalDiagnoses <- currentdx_count1[c(findtotal)]
```

Gets me closer but it is finding the total count for each column separately which is not what I need. I want a single column to encompass counts for each SID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the dataframe with the value of 3 or 4 and then use `rowSums` to count :

```
currentdx_count1$TotalDiagnoses <- rowSums(currentdx_count1[-1] == 3 | 
                                           currentdx_count1[-1] == 4)
currentdx_count1$TotalDiagnoses
#[1] 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
```